# Linking object references in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm doing this project in java where an objects a has an array, a. Then, you take a part of the array and assign it to another object, s, such that changing values in s changes them in a. I'm banging my head over this, I'm just not *getting* it. There is some concept that I'm missing.

```
public class IntArray implements IntSequence {

int[] a;

public IntArray(int size) {
    a = new int[size];
}

public int length() {
}

public int get(int index) {
    return a[index];
}

public void set(int index, int value) {
    a[index] = value;
}

public IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size) {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntSequence a = new IntArray(5);
    a.set(0, 11);
    a.set(1, 22);
    a.set(3, 33);
    // some more values

    IntSequence s = a.subSequence(2, 2);
    s.set(0, 100);
    s.set(1, 200);

    System.out.println(a.get(2)); // prints 100. 

    }
}


public interface IntSequence {
int length();

int get(int index);

void set(int index, int value);

IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size);
}
```

Could someone give me a nudge in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Where is the `subSequence` body?

Comment: I have to write it, I'm just too much of noob at this to understand how...

Comment: Where did this `IntSequence` class come from?

Comment: It's an interface that initializes each of the methods.

Comment: could you also add in the IntSequence interface to your question?

Comment: are you allowed to change the existing methods set() and get()?

Comment: yes, those can be anything. what I have there is just my initial attempt.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can do it.

I think the simplest way is by creating a new class that is a subsequence.

```
public class SubSequence implements IntSequence {
    private int[] a;
    private int start;
    private int size;

    public constructor(int[] arr, int start, int size) {
        this.a = arr;
        this.start = start;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public int get (int index){
        return a[start + index];
    }

    public IntSequence subSequence(int start, int size) { 
        return new SubSequence(a, start, size);
    }
    // And so on
}
```

Another way is by returning an anonymous class. You have to make your variables final to access them from the anonymous class. This is slightly better because you don't need a constructor, you should just be able to create lists from existing lists by calling the `subSequence` method.

```
public IntSequence subSequence(final int start, final int size) {

    return new IntSequence() {
        public int length() {
            return size;
        }
        public int get(index) {
            return a[start + index ]
        }
        ... and so on
    }
}
```

This code has no error checking, you should add that to make sure you don't reach beyond the array boundaries,

Comment: I was going to say that there's no straightforward way, e.g. without creating a backing class.

Comment: This makes more sense to me, but (unfortunately) it has to be done with only the original methods and classes.

Comment: @Brent I'm not sure what you mean, those are the original methods. The second example doesn't even need a concrete class.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is new to me. It has to follow the skeleton.

Comment: @Brent My second example is the code you can just pop in to method body you are missing, as long as you can change your variables to be final. If you can't, you can create local final references. If there are some requirements, you should post it in the question, instead of revealing them slowly (causing more work for whoever is trying to help you)

Comment: I'll be sure to be more clear in the future. thank you for helping me.